# With 2 forms on same view, why can I only enter text into the second form?

Tags: jquery, html, model-view-controller

I have a view, which has 2 forms, the weird thing is I can only enter text into the textbox in the second form.

To start with, both div's ManualLogin and ForgotLogin have their opacity set to 0, this is while the code tries to auto authenticate the user, on failure the ManualLogin div has its opacity set to 1. Clicking the 'Forgot Credentials' toggles the div's opacity of ManualLogin to 0, ForgotLogin to 1.

So as it stands, the username and password textboxes cannot have text entered, the email textbox can be entered into.

If I swap the ForgotLogin div to be before the ManualLogin div, I can enter text into the username and password fields but not the email field.

If I set it up so both forms display at the same time, text can entered into all boxes.

What is causing this and how do I fix it?

```
<div id="MainLoginDiv">
    <div id="LoginHeaderDiv" class="text-center">
        <h3 id="LoginHeader" class="page-header" style="color:white;">&nbsp;</h3>
    </div>
    <div id="ManualLogin" class="box" style="border: none;">
        @using (Html.BeginForm())
        {
            @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label" style="color:white;">Username</label>
                @Html.TextBox("username", null, new { id = "username", @class = "form-control", @Value="us" })
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label" style="color:white;">Password</label>
                @Html.TextBox("password", null, new { id = "password", @class = "form-control", @Value = "pwd" })
            </div>
            <div class="text-center" style="margin-top:40px;">
                <input type="button" id="ManualLoginBtn" value="Sign in" class="btn btn-primary" />
                <br />
                <input type="button" id="AutoLoginBtn" value="Auto Authenticate" class="btn btn-default" />
                <input type="button" id="ForgotLoginBtn" value="Forgot Credentials" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        }
    </div>
    <div id="ForgotLogin" class="box" style="border: none;">
        @using (Html.BeginForm())
        {
            @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label" style="color:white;">Email</label>
                @Html.TextBox("email", null, new { id = "email", @class = "form-control", @Value = "jhjhblah" })
            </div>
            <div class="text-center" style="margin-top:40px;">
                <input type="button" id="BackToLoginBtn" value="Back" class="btn btn-default" />
                <input type="button" id="ForgotSubmitBtn" value="Submit" class="btn btn-primary" />
            </div>
        }
    </div>
```

To toggle these div's I'm just using jquery to change the css opacity e.g.

```
$("#ManualLogin").css("opacity", "0");
$("#ForgotLogin").css("opacity", "1");
```

Comment: Have you checked with toggle()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use

```
    $("#ManualLogin").css("display", "none");
    $("#ForgotLogin").css("display", "block");
```

Comment: I'll try it out shortly, so what is it doing to cause such an issue?

Comment: The opacity property adds transparency to the background of an element This makes the text inside a transparent element hard to read, but it is present there.

Comment: Looking at it a bit further even though the second div is transparent the mouse cursor is responding to the invisible div elements still and it just so happens that the second div is above the first blocking the textboxes.